# Faux pas during/after signing job offer

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, hiring-process

I've been working as a programmer at Company A while applying to others, and I recently got a job offer from Company B. The B position is a large company and a huge jump for me, and I feel fortunate to have gotten the offer. I signed the offer electronically and gave notice to A on Monday, but I haven't actually gotten any kind of response from B since then.

This might not be a major issue, but we had some conflict when going over the employment paperwork in regards to some forms that seemed to me
to be impossible to fill out correctly. I read them to mean that I was required to list everything I'd ever made, which felt like an incorrect reading, especially given that there was only space to list one thing in an immutable digital form. I asked for clarification, and was told that I'd get it when Legal got back to the HR person. That said, I felt a bit of pressure to just sign it so we could move on.

I did my best to navigate it diplomatically, and I'm usually good at that, but now I'm feeling like I might have bothered someone enough that they are reconsidering me. Legal never responded, and when I received the job offer, I did end up filling out the forms as they directed, noting my most important project, and the fact that the list wasn't exhaustive.

I'm not completely screwed if B reneges, as A makes a point of being extremely flexible and rehiring old employees whenever possible, but it would be quite awkward. I'm currently holding off on sending my goodbye/team-wide-notification email, and only a few supervisors and coworker friends know of my intent.

So my question is, given this, should I be worried about B reneging, and should I pump the brakes on leaving A as a result? Or am I probably just being paranoid?

**UPDATE:** Jim Clay is correct, I talked to them and everything is fine. Thanks for assuaging my nerves ya'll. I'm gonna leave this question up in the hopes that it brings some peace to other nervous people in the future.

Comment: I don't think any of us can accurately determine if you've upset someone or if B will take any action. The good news is, you can just pick up the phone, call your contact at B, and check the specifics (your start date, whatever). Sometimes, phone conversations are the best for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably fine.  While it is not 100% unheard of for companies to back out of written and signed offers, it is pretty close.  At that point they have to deal with potential legal issues, which they would really rather not do.

Long story short, you're probably fine.

Try to contact the recruiter and/or HR person you worked with.  They should be able to tell you where things are at.